# Jquery - Getting 403 error when submitting form via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a php page called form.php. When you go to this page it shows a form, when that form is submitted I have jquery code that posts the form to itself via ajax. This works for other pages, however this specific page/code is giving me a 403 error when the page is submitted. The main difference is the other pages that work are located in a sub folder while form.php is in the root directory. Here is the jquery code:

```
$.ajax({
type:'POST',
cache:false,
url:'/form.php?action=add',
data:formData,
dataType:'json',
success: function(data) {})
});
```

I understand this is a server error, my question is why would it fail pointing to itself via the root folder but not fail if posted to a page in a sub folder?

Comment: Try a tool like fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to analyze if the request. Great for finding URL errors on dynamic requests.

Comment: Test it with `Firebug` it's routes issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. One of the fields I was storing 2 variables in one value like so:

1<>2

I guess the <> part was triggering some issues, once I removed that it worked without any issues. Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
url:'.../form.php?action=add',
```

Comment: No still not working, if I do it a few more times cpanel auto blocks me too. Blah this sucks!

Answer (score 0):

use the full URL to the file http://blah.com/form.php.